# How do I differentiate between processes with the same name

Tags: c#, process

How can I tell the difference between multiple processes with the same name?

I have a program that will launch the same file with different parameters.  I can manage the processes just fine unless the parent program crashes.  The launched processes are able to run w/o the parent.  When I relaunch the program, how can I tell the difference between each instance?

Comment: Is the PID not an option?

Comment: PID does differentiate between the two, but I won't know what set of arguments I passed to it.  I can't check the arguments the process started with.  I could end up closing the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to query for the command line arguments using WMI and a given PID like this:

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = 1234"))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mo["CommandLine"]);
    }
}
```

Copied from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8efe163b-927e-4895-9983-b8c47b515d7c/how-to-get-the-command-line-parameters-from-a-different-process-in-c

Comment: Thank you, this worked after a little playing with it.  It does not like running in debug mode. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can differentiate using the process id:

```
Process myProcess = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyProgram\\Program.exe");
int processId = myProcess.Id;
```

**processId** is the key here.

Comment: I use that while the parent program is running.  What I need is to tell the difference between two processes running with the same name after the parent program restarts.  The processes can run independent of the parent.

Comment: why don't you try to log the PIDs somehwere, so that on the restart of your main program you'll be able to know which is which

Comment: This was where I was going to go if I could not get another way to work.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was super helpful.